# Regular expression to find repetitions of arbitrary characters

Tags: php, regex, elvis-operator

I have a large PHP codebase with many instances of this pattern:

`$result = $expression? $expression: $alternate;`

Which I want to replace with:

`$result = $expression ?: $alternate;`

Here `$expression` can be anything like `$this->system->cache('1234')`. It will usually start with `$`, and usually not have any spaces in it. Those few that don't start with `$` or have spaces, I can review manually.

I can get a RegEx to match the above, allowing for optional whitespace:

`(\$[^? ]+) *\? *(\$[^: ]+) *:`

But this won't guarantee that group 1 and group 2 are the same.

Is there a way to match these patterns?

Comment: share some input and expected output plz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use backreference `\1` -- reference to the first matching group, i.e.:

```
(\$[^? ]+) *\? *\1 *:
```